# Refit and authorization header

Tags: c#, asp.net-authorization, refit

Currently, I am adding an authorization header to my request like this:

File: SomeFile.cs

```
public interface ITestApi
{
    [Get("/api/test/{id}")]
    Task<string> GetTest([Header("Authorization")] string authorization, int id);

    [Get("/api/tests/")]
    Task<string> GetTests([Header("Authorization")] string authorization);
}
```

File: SomeOtherFile.cs

```
var username = "xxx";
var password = "yyy";
var authHeader = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
var baseAddress = "https://my.test.net";
ITestApi myApi = RestService.For<ITestApi>(baseAddress);

int id = 123;
var test= myApi.GetTest(authHeader, id);

var tests = myApi.GetTests(authHeader);
```

Is there a way to set the authHeader globally so that I don't have to pass it as a parameter to every call? (I am using Refit version 4.6.48). In other words, I'd like to be able to do the calls like this:

```
var test= myApi.GetTest(id);

var tests = myApi.GetTests();
```

Answer (score 21):

I found a solution:

```
[Headers("Authorization: Basic")]
public interface ITestApi
{
    [Get("/api/test/{id}")]
    Task<string> GetTest(int id);

    [Get("/api/tests/")]
    Task<string> GetTests();
}


var username = "xxx";
var password = "yyy";
var authHeader = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
var baseAddress = "https://my.test.net";

var refitSettings = new RefitSettings()
{
    AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = () => Task.FromResult(authHeader)
};

ITestApi myApi = RestService.For<ITestApi>(baseAddress, refitSettings);

int id = 123;
var test= myApi.GetTest(id);

var tests = myApi.GetTests();
```

Comment: Great! The important part here that makes the `AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter` part work, and not get ignored, is the attribute on the interface.

`[Headers("Authorization: Basic")]`

that has to be there, including the `: <scheme>` part of it to Refit to invoke the `AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter`.

Comment: What if we want a dynamic scheme for Authorization? The "Basic" in this case.

Comment: This is the correct answer!

Comment: Is there a way to set the header name?

Answer (score 8):

thd's answer did not work for me because Refit is currently [simply](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/573) [ignoring](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/689) `AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter` and the requests do not contain the authentication header.

I could make it work by providing my `HttpClient` with a default authentication header:

```
string token = await GetTokenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
string endpointUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(endpointVariable) ??
                     defaultEndpointUrl ?? DefaultEndpointUrl;

var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler())
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(endpointUrl)
};
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

//TODO: remove as this is ignored anyway
//var refitSettings = new RefitSettings
//{
//    AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = () => Task.FromResult($"{token}")
//};

var builder = RequestBuilder.ForType<TApiClient>();
return RestService.For(client, builder);
```

---

GetTokenAsync looks like the following:

```
public static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
    // theoretically the token could have expired during the tests, but there is very low chance
    // so returning the same token if one was generated
    lock (SyncLock)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Token))
            return Token;
    }

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
    {
        Address = $"{IdentityServerUrl}/connect/token",
        ClientId = "MY_CLIENT_APITEST",
        ClientSecret = IdentityServerPass,
        Scope = "api.read"

    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    tokenResponse.HttpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    lock (SyncLock)
    {
        Token = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
        return Token;
    }
}
```

Comment: and using *OAuth Token*: `grant_type=client_credentials &client_id=example_client_id &client_secret=example_client_secret &scope=user.read` ?

Comment: What is ***GetTokenAsync*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet It is used to get a valid token from the authentication server.

Comment: @Kiquenet I have finally remembered to search for this code and add it to the answer.

Comment: great !! you're my idol

Comment: Code of GetAccessTokenAsync not for production. Because every request trying to obtain this lock. It's overhead. Best practice in this case is check for IsNullOrWhiteSpace and return existing value before lock

Answer (score 7):

Refit has changed its approach. Now it uses the default .NET HttpHandler

```
var handler = new AuthHandler(credentials.Username, credentials.Password);
var githubApi = RestService.For<IGithubApi>(new HttpClient(handler)
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com")
                });


public class AuthHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    private readonly string _username;
    private readonly string _password;

    public AuthHandler(string username, 
        string password)
    {
        _username = username;
        _password = password;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "<your user name or app name>");
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                $"{_username}:{_password}")));

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work. Seems like refit removes authorization in header. Tested on Xamarin without DI, just direct. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

you can register Refit with the client factory in the startup. if you do that then you can use a MessageHandler class to manage headers globally. here I have an example:

in the startup register your main refit interface:

```
var apiUrl = _configuration.GetValue<string>("API_URL");
services.AddRefitClient<IMyApi>()
        .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<MyApiHeaderHandler>();
services.AddTransient<MyApiHeaderHandler>();
```

this is my MyApiHeaderHandle class:

```
public class MyApiHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
     private readonly TokenManager _tokenManager;
     public MyApiHeaderHandler(TokenManager tokenManager)
     {
         _tokenManager = tokenManager;
     }
     protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
     SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken 
     cancellationToken)
     {
         var token = await _tokenManager.GetToken();
         request.Headers.Authorization = new 
 AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
     }
}
```

in the TokenManager class, I manage to cache the token and to renew it when it is removed.

and this is my refit interface:

```
public interface IMyApi
{
     [Get("/SomeEndPoint")]
     Task<IEnumerable<MyApiResponse>> 
 GetCustomerContracts(string input,
         CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

this solution is based on the Refit docs:
[here](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit?tab=readme-ov-file#bearer-authentication)