# How to add a static authorization header with refit in xamarin.forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, refit

i'm trying to add a static authorization Header with basic authentication, but when i do the request, the server response is negative. So, i tried to add it in this way:

```
[Headers("Authorization: Basic","Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" )]

public interface IRouteApi
{
    [Post("/getRoute?dtxIni={Ini}&dtxFin={Fin}")]
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> getPathInfo(int Ini, int Fin);
}
```

Then i got a static Config class:

```
public static class Config
{
    public static string ApiUrl = "http://www2.baseUrl.it/Base";
    static string username = "aaa";
    static string password = "bbb";
    public static string authHeader = 
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

    public static RefitSettings refitSettings = new RefitSettings()
    {
        AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter = () => Task.FromResult(authHeader)
    };
}
RestService.For<T>(client,Config.refitSettings);
```

But it doesn't work and the requests are not authorized.
I follow this question too: [Refit and authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887468/refit-and-authorization-header), but it doesn't convince me, because he/she put a dynamic header in his/her api definition.
Maybe the problem is in the multiple headers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your authorization header never changes, you don't really need to use `AuthorizationHeaderValueGetter` (which is intended to be used for more dynamic auth scenarios). Instead, just use the `DefaultRequestHeaders` dictionary on your `HttpClient`:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com"),
    DefaultRequestHeaders = 
    {
        {"Authorization", $"Basic {authHeader}"}
    }
};

var api = RestService.For<IYourApi>(client);
```

Comment: and using **OAuth Token** _authorization_: `grant_type=client_credentials &client_id=example_client_id &client_secret=example_client_secret &scope=user.read` ?